# How send data form one controller to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript

I have a problem with data in controller.
Can i send variable like 'this.channel' from one controller to another?

Thanks.
There is my code:
This first main controller

```
export class NotificationTemplateController extends AbstractEdit<any> {

  public static $inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$injector',
  ];
  public source: any;
  public channel: any;

  constructor($scope: any, $injector: any) {
    super($scope, $injector);
    this.channel = this.$scope.__searchMain.searchFieldList[3].$ngModel;
  }
```

Second controller:

```
export class NotificationParamsController {

  public static $inject = [
    '$scope',
  ];
  private source: any;

  constructor($scope: any) {}}
```

Comment: use event emitter for send contoller communication or services.

Comment: @RahulSharma Hello, i tried use like this http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/how-to-work-with-event-emitters-in-angularjs but, it's not working may be i did same mistake in typescript.

Comment: I would consider removing the AngularJS tag as this is Angular 2.0 not AngularJS. There are many Angular2 tags. This will get this question in front of the appropriate SO users. Thanks!

Comment: Use a parent `controller` to handle a common (global) scope.